# Problem with floating button on page load

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a website with a page that contains links to pages in the same website. I need to have the link open in a new tab, with a CHAT button floating over the page in the new tab, or (if needed) sit at the top of the page. However, the button is not showing up on the new tab when it is opened.

The website is running on Ubuntu 18.04 with Nginx. Does anyone know what I can add or change to get it to show up?

I should add that I don't mind if the new page needs to be loaded into a thin border frame in order to make it work (e.g iframe) - as long as it dynamically adjusts to the size of the new page.

Here's how the code looks in each file: In one file (index9.php) I have the following code:

```js
/// Get all links on the page
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

// Add an event listener to each link
links.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    // Prevent the default link behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Open the link in a new tab
    const newTab = window.open('', '_blank');
    newTab.location.href = link.href;

    // Inject the floating button into the new tab's content document
    newTab.document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      const button = document.createElement('button');
      button.innerHTML = 'Chat';
      button.style.backgroundColor = 'green'; // Change the chat button background to green
      button.onclick = function() {
        // Open the chat window in a new tab
        window.open('chat.php', '_blank');
      };

      newTab.document.body.appendChild(button);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<h1>Welcome to My Website</h1>
<p><a href="about.html" target="_blank" onclick="executeScript()">About</a></p>
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

I have tried numerous iterations. All of them result in the new page opening properly, but the floating button is not showing up there.

Comment: Appending content to a separate tab/window instance is incredibly unreliable (assuming it's even possible any more). A much better approach would be to have the button load as part of the content in the new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to force the browser to append HTML overtop of a new tab due to browser security. An alternative would be to create a proxy page to handle displaying the page, and overlaying your chat button on that page.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Proxy Page</title>
    <style>
        #chatButton {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 20px;
            right: 20px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    // 'default.php' is page to load when no URL specified
    $url = $_GET['url'] ?? 'default.php'; // get URL or set default
    echo file_get_contents($url); // load content of URL
    ?>

    <button id="chatButton" onclick="window.open('chat.php', '_blank');">Chat</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And if you want to keep the links on the initial page less confusing, you can do something like this:

```
<p><a href="https://example.com" class="new-tab-link">Example.com</a></p>
<p><a href="https://wikipedia.org" class="new-tab-link">Wikipedia</a></p>

<script>
    const links = document.querySelectorAll('.new-tab-link');

    links.forEach(link => {
        link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();

            const proxyUrl = 'proxy.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent(link.href);
            window.open(proxyUrl, '_blank');
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you would prefer not to use PHP, you can achieve the same thing with just JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Proxy Page</title>
    <style>
        iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 80vh;
            border: none;
        }
        #chatButton {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 20px;
            right: 20px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="contentFrame" src=""></iframe>
    <button id="chatButton" onclick="window.open('chat.php', '_blank');">Chat</button>

    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var url = window.location.hash.substring(1); // Get URL from hash
            document.getElementById('contentFrame').src = decodeURIComponent(url);
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the corresponding referrer page:

```
<p><a href="https://example.com" class="new-tab-link">Example.com</a></p>
<p><a href="https://wikipedia.org" class="new-tab-link">Wikipedia</a></p>

<script>
    const links = document.querySelectorAll('.new-tab-link');

    links.forEach(link => {
        link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();

            const proxyUrl = 'proxy.html#' + encodeURIComponent(link.href);
            window.open(proxyUrl, '_blank');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I am trying to test your second approach using javascript. However, I'm not sure I've got the files loaded and named correctly. Here is what I have now:

Comment: @MarkKnittel It looks like your comment got cut. What specifically are you having issues with? If you want to show me a sample of your code, you can put it in a jsfiddle.

Comment: It definitely did... I'll try again: I placed the JS code into a module named script.js, and added the referrer code with the links into index9.html, inside the body section. Both files are in the same folder. When I click on a link to a local html in the same folder from index9.html it opens a new tab with a dummy header from the root at top, and a frame at the bottom with a 404 error. Any ideas what I did wrong? I should add a couple of things to help: 1) Security is not an issue here - this is an offline education server in Africa. 2) I'm also OK with a frame on the new page if that helps.

Comment: @MarkKnittel Try putting the url to your desired page directly into the url of the proxy page 'proxy.html#newpage.html' and then reload the page (make sure to reload because simply pressing enter won't reload the page content when a hash is in the url). If it's not getting 404 anymore, then it means its a problem with the referrer page, if it is then it means it's a problem with the proxy page. Then we can go from there. Also is the javascript for the proxy page in-line or in script.js?

Comment: OK. Here's the line with the link in it: <p><a href="about.html" class="new-tab-link">About</a></p>. That opens fine without the class statement replaced with target="_blank". The js is in two places: this part is in index9.php: <script>
    const links = document.querySelectorAll('.new-tab-link');

    links.forEach(link => {
        link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();

            const proxyUrl = 'proxy.html#' + encodeURIComponent(link.href);
            window.open(proxyUrl, '_blank');
        });
    });

Comment: The script.js file has this in it: 
<body>
    <iframe id="contentFrame" src=""></iframe>
    <button id="chatButton" onclick="window.open('chat.php', '_blank');">Chat</button>

    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var url = window.location.hash.substring(1); // Get URL from hash
            document.getElementById('contentFrame').src = decodeURIComponent(url);
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>.... I don't see any label in either file defining "new-tab-link"/. Is that part of the problem?

Comment: @MarkKnittel Your js file should not have html in it... put that code in your script.js file into proxy.html instead.

Comment: I did that, but may not have the right js content in proxy.html now. However, just to simplify things - I'd like to try your first approach without the JS as I think that will work fine. 2 questions: 1) What should the links look like in that example, and where should I put them? 2) If the point of the second insert above about keeping the links less confusing - where should I add that code, and do I need to remove anything when I add that? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MarkKnittel If your going with the first method, it'll require PHP so make sure your proxy page is a php file (proxy.php). On index9.html put all links from the second block of code anywhere on the page, and put the JavaScript at the bottom of the page in the `<script>` tags, just before your `</body>` tag. Then on proxy.php, put the entire first block of code and nothing else. From here, it should be working. Then if you want to change some things, add a header, etc. feel free to see what works. Since you tagged PHP in your post, I'm assuming you have PHP.

Comment: OK, that worked! Now I need to figure how to map the changes into the rest of the site pages in different folders, etc. I use a master index with htmlf files that point to pages outside the root via ports, etc., so it will be a bit complicated. I'll work on that. Thanks for your help!!!!!

Comment: @MarkKnittel Glad to hear it's working, could you please accept the answer if it has sufficiently answered your question.

Comment: Done. Thanks again.